# Downloading files from a remote server directory listing and import into HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-commons, flume, flume-ng, apache-commons-io

I have been given access to a server that provides a directory listing of files which I will download and import into HDFS.  What I am currently doing is hitting the server with an HTTP GET and downloading the HTML directory listing and then I use jsoup and parse all the links to the files which I need to download.  Once I have a complete list I download each files one by one and then import each into HDFS.  I don't believe that flume is able to read & parse html to download files.   Is there an easier cleaner way to do what I am describing?

Answer (score 0):

With Flume I would do the following:

1) have a process grep you URLs and store the dumped HTML file to a directory

2) Configure a SpoolDir source pointing to that directory with a customer deserializer:

```
deserializer    LINE    Specify the deserializer used to parse the file into events. Defaults to parsing each line as an event. The class specified must implement EventDeserializer.Builder.
```

that deserializer reads the HTML file and extracts the HTML file with JSoup. The extracted bits are then converted to multiple events in the desired format and sent to HDFSSink

That's basically it.